# What other OS installation options are available when things go terribly wrong

Tags: networking, installation

i have a Toshiba Tecra 9100.The Dvd rom isn't functioning so its in an unreliable form.I have a usb port that is working.The laptop has no working OS installed however there are files under C:\WINDOWS from a past failed install.

I have a high speed internet.Are there any ways that i can be able to use to install an OS,any OS to this laptop.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the bios allow booting from that usb port ?

Comment: I checked this and it does not support booting from a us port.

Comment: According to some VERY quick research on possibly somewhat unreliable forums, I found that the Toshiba Tecra 9100 should have the option to boot from USB. Try tapping the F12 at boot up and see if USB is an option.

Comment: there's always slaving the HD into another computer and installing a linux distro that way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options but the best would be using [USB](http://www.blogsdna.com/2016/how-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-drive-without-windows-7-iso-dvd.htm). Just note, some older PCs don't give you the option to boot from a USB drive without a BIOS update, or some, not at all. You can checkout [network installation](http://www.ehow.com/way_5272460_install-windows-over-network.html) too if you like, but it's more for a enterprise then a user.

If you have no other options, consider using an external cd/DVD rom or replacing the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in your bios if you have any other boot option. Installing debian from network is described [here](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/ch04s05.html). Some bios don't have an option for booting from usb port, but present a usb stick as a hard drive when you ask to choose boot media.